# Externally-located 'npm run' scripts in package.json on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, bash, npm

As we know, you can run arbitrary commands using `npm run` by adding a `scripts` hash to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "browserify browser/main.js | uglifyjs -mc > static/bundle.js"
}
```

Which would then be run with `npm run build-js`.

You can also move these commands out into separate scripts, such as bash scripts, as such:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "bin/build.sh"
}
```

This obviously doesn't natively work on Windows, due to Windows not being capable of running bash scripts. You can install bash ports and such, but I'd love to be able to use some sort of native Windows construct for doing the same thing.

I've tried some other approaches, including using `child_process.exec` to run arbitrary commands from within a standard node script file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "node bin/build.js"
}
```

But I've noticed `child_process` chokes on relatively large/intensive operations, making it implausible to use.

Is there a Windows-specific (or even better, cross-platform) way to move these `package.json` `npm run` scripts out into separate files? Preferably one that doesn't require bash?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [a helpful article](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/8681-how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool-replacing-gruntgulp/) on using NPM as a build tool, why not simply use a JavaScript file?

Here's the example given in the article (slightly modified for clarity):

```
// scripts/favicon.js

var favicons = require('favicons');  
var path = require('path');  

favicons({  
  source: path.resolve('../assets/images/logo.png'),
  dest: path.resolve('../dist/'),
});


// package.json

"scripts": {
  "build-favicon": "node scripts/favicon.js",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "favicons": "latest",
}
```

Which would be run in the terminal with the command `npm run build-favicon`

Answer (score 3):

Using node to run a JS file is an option, but if you need to run system commands on both Windows and *NIX, that would make the script messy.  For cross-platform scripts, try out the [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) package.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `make` command is also a nice option.

Makefile

```
build-js:
    browserify browser/main.js | uglifyjs -mc > static/bundle.js
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "make build-js",
}
```

You can find more about `make`  [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).