# How to output JS/JSON in NPM Script

Tags: json, npm

From my last question - [npm version "scripts have access to the new version in package.json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179144/npm-version-scripts-have-access-to-the-new-version-in-package-json)

How do you output JS / JSON from an NPM script.  After an `npm version` I am writing that out to a JS / JSON file to be picked up in Angular with an import like what I've written at the bottom of this post

I tried these variations of the following:

```
"version": "version=$(git tag | head -1); echo \"{version:$version}\" > client/src/app/config-from-npm.json",
```

- single quote (') instead of double (") in all cases
- `echo '\{version:...` - error Unexpected token { in JSON
- `echo '%7Bversion:...` - outputs '%7Bversion ...'
- `echo '%7Bversion:...` - outputs '{version ...'

#### Angular import of version number

What I'm trying to achieve and how it will be used:

```
 export var config = {
     version: v1.0.0
 }

 ----

 import { config } from './config';
```

If I don't work out this '{' in JS / JSON problem I will just write the version number to file and read in.  Nowhere near as neat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yipee, I worked it out.  Unicode character entities - https://unicode-table.com/en/#007B

Where it has 'U+007B' for '{', I used '\u007B'.

Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forging a json string with shell commands, use tools that are json aware.

Here is an example using [jq command line parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) :

```
$ echo "v1.0.0" | jq -R '{"version":.}'
{
   "version": "v1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Sounds great.  Tho that would still sit inside the `package.json / scripts` and thus suffer the same problem.  I suppose this or my attempt could be written in an external script (and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28047101/1019307 this is possible).